# How do I vendor a package which itself vendors another package?

Tags: go, package, vendoring

I am trying to write an application that uses [this package](https://github.com/ChimeraCoder/anaconda). I have the following snippet:

```
import (
    "github.com/ChimeraCoder/anaconda"
    "github.com/garyburd/go-oauth/oauth"
)

c, _, err := anaconda.GetCredentials(&oauth.Credentials{}, "...")
```

This results in the following compilation error:

```
app.go:40:9: cannot use "github.com/garyburd/go-oauth/oauth".Credentials literal
  (type *"github.com/garyburd/go-oauth/oauth".Credentials) as type
  *"github.com/ChimeraCoder/anaconda/vendor/github.com/garyburd/go-oauth/oauth".Credentials
  in argument to anaconda.GetCredentials
```

This is because `github.com/ChimeraCoder/anaconda` is using vendoring.

How then can I create an instance of `*oauth.Credentials`?

Comment: You can't have nested vendor directories. You need to use a vendoring tool to flatten these into your top-level vendor directory (or do it manually if you choose)

Comment: And open an issue with the library maintainer! Libraries should not vendor their dependencies for exactly this reason.